# Joomla 3 loop through multidimensional array for db insert

Tags: php, joomla

this is my first question here so please be nice :)

I'm trying to insert multiple records, but I keep getting a mysql error, #1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1.  I've followed the guide here: http://docs.joomla.org/Inserting,_Updating_and_Removing_data_using_JDatabase

Part of my issue is that the columns won't necessarily always be the same in the array.  For example, 'address1' is required, but 'address2' and 'address3' are not. All available fields exist in the db table though, so I just need to specify the columns as keys for each value set.

I feel like I'm missing something quite obvious, but having spent far too many hours at this, I hope someone will be able to easily point it out.

Here's my error:
1136 Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 SQL=INSERT INTO `jos_supersite_contact`

Below is the code I'm using....

```
        foreach ($data[0]['result'] as $results) {
            $db = JFactory::getDbo();
            $db->getQuery(true);
            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                $columns[] = $db->quoteName(str_replace('.', '_', $key));
                $rows[] = $db->quote($value);
            }
            $query
                    ->columns($columns)
                    ->values(implode(',',$rows))
                    ->insert($db->quoteName('#__supersite_contact'));
            $db->setQuery($query);
            if (!$db->execute()) {
                throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You error message itself explain the issue.

The column filed and values fields are not matching in number.

you already mentioned that `address1` is  required and `address2,3` not  so in your query the column have 3 fields every time but value have only `address1` when `2 and 3` empty. So make sure all time you have these three fields even those have `null` value

Also I noticed the Query you are using inside the loop it give more load to the DB. Instead of using like that use like below.

```
       $db = JFactory::getDbo();
       $columns = "column1,column2,column3";
       //This is what you need to loop.
       $vals    = "('$db->quote($val1)','$db->quote($val2)','$db->quote($val3)')
                  ,('$db->quote($val1)','$db->quote($val2)','$db->quote($val3)')
                  ,('$db->quote($val1)','$db->quote($val2)','$db->quote($val3)')"; 
       $query
               ->columns($columns)
               ->values($vals)
               ->insert($db->quoteName('#__supersite_contact'));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        if (!$db->execute()) {
            throw new Exception($db->getErrorMsg());
        }
```

[This is much effective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5591514/insert-multiple-rows-using-a-single-query) in multiple row insert situations.

Hope it make sense..

Comment: I'm getting a 500 server error trying it this way, so I'll need to figure out what's going on with that... will post back shortly.